# Run multiple gulp4 tasks programmatically

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-4

How to run multiple node streams (generated by gulp) sequentially?

Let's assume a simple gulpfile with two depending tasks:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("do1", function() {
  return gulp.src("./test/*")
             .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest/"));
});

gulp.task("do2", function() {
  return gulp.src("./dest/*")
             .pipe(gulp.dest("./final/"));
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.series("do1", "do2"));
```

What I came up with so far:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");

function do1() {
  return gulp.src("./test/*")
             .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest/"));
}

function do2() {
  return gulp.src("./dest/*")
             .pipe(gulp.dest("./final/"));
}

gulp.task("do1", function() {
  return do1();
});

gulp.task("do2", function() {
  return do2();
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.series("do1", "do2"));

// ...
// somewhere else in the same file, with some preconditions ...
do1().on("finish", do2);
```

Indeed this is working for this simple example, but is there a more convenient / elegant way? In particular for longer dependency chains. Maybe a solution using `gulp.series` and execute the whole series?

Answer (score 0):

Gulp tasks can depend on each other (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps--fn):

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("do1", function() {
  return gulp.src("./test/*")
             .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest/"));
});

gulp.task("do2", function() {
  return gulp.src("./dest/*")
             .pipe(gulp.dest("./final/"));
});

gulp.task("do3", ["do1", "do2"], function() {
  console.log("Tasks do1 and do2 are finished");
});

gulp.task("default", ["do3"], function() {
  console.log("All default tasks are finished");
});
```

Comment: First thing: gulp4, second thing: programmatically not from a gulp task. You'd be right I could execute `gulp.run("default");` but that is deprecated in gulp 4.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!